# WSO2 ESB - Data Services Server Feature - How to use Data Sources to swap data source on fly

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.0.3. I have installed WSO2 Data Services Feature on it and I have created DS.

There is feature in the ESB under "Configure" tab under admin UI where you can define the "Data Source".

My question is while creating new Data Service I am not able to use this "Data Source" which I have configured in ESB. We have different environments DEV / TEST / UAT / PROD. Each environment has different data base for same data service.

Currently I have manually change the DS XML file to point to new DB and then deploy.

Is there a way to point to the DB configured in ESB and change the DB for DS on the fly?

thanks
ABhijit

07/01/2012 - 
Any update on this please ? This is Apple POC in their big group. If suceedded WSO2 will have Apple implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the dataservices features in to the same ESB instance that you've already been using, then it should be possible for you to use the datasources created via "Configure > Data Sources" menu. Because, when you create a particular datasource via the aforesaid option, it is visible to all the other installed features (that use datasources). But if you're having ESB and DSS in two boxes, the datasources defined in let's say ESB are not visible the DSS node unless you're having those nodes mounted to the same registry. However, this functionality too will be there in the next immediate upcoming release.

However, I'd suggest you the following pattern to get your requirement done. I;m assuming you're having DataServices features installed into ESBs in all your environments DEV / TEST / UAT / PROD. If so, you can create datasources using the "same name" (for eg: assume you have a datasource named "ds1" created in all 4 environments) via the "Configure > DataSources" menu pointing to different database configurations that you'll be using in each of those environments. Then you can point to the created datasource inside the DBS (dataservice discripters) as shown below.

```
<data name="TestDataService">
   <config id="default">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">ds1</property>
   </config>
   .....
</data>
```

Once you're done with those steps, whenever you deploy your dataservice in any of your environments, it will point to the relevant datasource without requiring you to reconfigure the database configurations manually and the relevant database configurations specific to each environment will be loaded dynamically at the runtime.

Hope the above explanation helps!

Regards,
Prabath

Comment: thank you very much, Prabath. One more question though, you can not export those data sources as XML I believe. Not it shows up in the directory structure in the WSO2 ESB 4.0.3. I believe it is stored in registry. Is that understanding correct? Also I can not create this in eclipse plugin as well. So I can not deploy this as a part of car file. Is there any work around here? Thanks again for help. Abhijit

Comment: Yeah you've got absolutely right. When you use the management console to create datasources, the configurations get saved in the registry. And as you've correctly pointed out we didn't have an out of the box option to bundle the datasource configurations up within a car file in our earlier releases. (You can still do this as via the registry resource upload option that is available in the DevStudio. However this is purely a workaround but we don't recommend this). Therefore the most recommended workaround would be to use datasources.properties file to have your datasources configured.

Comment: If you use the aforementioned "datasources.properties" configuration file, you can configure all your datasources there in that particular file before the server start up and drop it inside "CARBON_HOME/repository/conf" directory. Then the datasource configurations would be picked up dynamically. The only disadvantage of using this approach would be, if you want to configure a new datasource or if you want to modify an existing configuration (if you do not opt to use the management console to edit the datasource configurations), then you will have to restart the server to reflect the changes.

Comment: I've added a sample "datasource.properties" configuration as a new answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks a lot Prabath. This is very helpful. I will give a try about properties file and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
#----- Start of the configuration -----

synapse.datasources=TestDS,TestDS1

synapse.datasources.icFactory=com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory
synapse.datasources.providerPort=2199

#TestDS Configuration
synapse.datasources.TestDS.registry=JNDI
synapse.datasources.TestDS.type=BasicDataSource
synapse.datasources.TestDS.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
synapse.datasources.TestDS.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB
synapse.datasources.TestDS.username=dummy_username
synapse.datasources.TestDS.password=dummy_password
synapse.datasources.TestDS.dsName=TestDS
synapse.datasources.TestDS.maxActive=100
synapse.datasources.TestDS.maxIdle=20
synapse.datasources.TestDS.maxWait=10000

#TestDS1 configuration
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.registry=JNDI
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.type=BasicDataSource
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB1
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.username=dummy_username
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.password=dummy_password
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.dsName=TestDS1
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.maxActive=100
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.maxIdle=20
synapse.datasources.TestDS1.maxWait=10000

#----- End of the configuration -----
```